# Soldering question: Which Kester solder to use (Resin-Five vs. SN63) in what situation

Tags: soldering

I have been soldering electronics projects for 60+ years but have forgotten (if I ever knew) which solder to use in which application.

Besides a few short lengths of unknown origin, I have 2 large rolls of Kester solder: Kester Resin-Five 40/60 (.092 dia) and Kester Solid Wire SN63 (.050 dia). The Resin-Five solder seems to melt at a lower temperature and flow better, but the finer Solid Wire solder looks cleaner like it is more appropriate for PCB soldering of small digital components.

I also have several choices of soldering irons ranging from 20-40 watt pencils to a bigger dual-power Weller soldering gun.  I have used the smaller irons on PCB components and the larger gun for larger line voltage wiring.

Can anyone give me some guidance on which solder and gun to use in various situations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Resin-Five solder seems to melt at a lower temperature and flow
> better, but the finer Solid Wire solder looks cleaner like it is more
> appropriate for PCB soldering of small digital components.

This matches my own preferences. Large diameter 60/40 rosin-cored solder for general use, finer diameter for small surface mount parts (with external flux from a 'flux pen'). For very fine work I sometimes use 0.7 mm.

SN63/PB37 '[eutectic](https://fctsolder.com/eutectic-solder/)' solder is supposed to be usable at a lower temperature and produce brighter joints than 60/40, but in practice I haven't found much difference between them.

> I also have several choices of soldering irons ranging from 20-40 watt
> pencils to a bigger dual-power Weller soldering gun. I have used the
> smaller irons on PCB components and the larger gun for larger line
> voltage wiring.

Again I think you have the right idea. I use a 40 watt temperature controlled soldering station for most PCB work, and a [Goot TQ-77](http://www.goot.jp/en/handakote/tq-77/) 20/200W 'gun' style iron for soldering heavy wires and connectors.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about using external flux. I have used soldering paste in plumbing applications but have mostly relied on resin core solder in electronics work. I'll see if I can find a 'flux pen' for use with the thinner solid wire solder.

Comment: "For very fine work I sometimes use 0.7 mm" Eh? That's huge!